# Spring boot SAML authentication with Duo as IdP getting re-redirected to spring form login page after IDP login

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml, duosecurity

Spring boot SAML authentication with Duo as IdP in staging ,getting re-redirected to spring form login page after IDP login.

While I have tried the same app in my local with Okta as IdP and it works.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<saml2-core.spring.version>1.0.10.RELEASE</saml2-core.spring.version>

WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter overrides:

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf()
    .disable();

    http
    .httpBasic()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint);

    http
    .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .addFilterBefore(samlFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    ...
  }

  Local :
  <saml2p:Response Destination="http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO" ID="id6615428662209589383819140"

 staging:
 <samlp:Response Destination="https://****.****.***/saml/SSO"


 I compared the saml request for both local and Prod and they look same.

 Please let know what i can check.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am securing an endpoint in my spring application with saml and Duo as IDP.I have done similar setup in my local with Okta as Idp and it works. When i configure the same for Duo in test environment (aws) and try to access the secured endpoint ,  it gets re-directed to Duo login .i login with creds and it gets re-directed to spring's default login page instead of application endpoint.I do not see any errors in log .so i am confused how to proceed in finding the actual issue.